# 'Community' keeps bumping old "dead" threads

Tags: discussion

For example, [this question from 2015](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/34728/demo-reel-feedback-for-student).

Now I assume this is because it doesn't have an 'Accepted' answer, but it's so old that

1. OP is long gone and unlikely to ever resolve it.
2. It's an old question so edits or other action may be a bit unwarrented.

Is there currently a system to close or otherwise file away such questions? Does making them as historical help?

How do other SE sites handle this?

Is this a feature-not-a-bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature, yes - the bump is to get some attention for old unanswered questions (unanswered meaning no upvoted answers, or no accepted answer.)

Some posts are abandoned, yes, but that's okay - if there are good answers they still provide value to the community.

The way to handle these generally is to upvote good answers, or leave a good answer yourself, but in this case it's an old question which was on topic back in the day but now off topic, so I have placed a historical lock on it.